# update multiple tables considering columns to update are in "where"

Tags: sql, sql-update

There are 3 tables - 1 parent and 2 child (child PK has FK to parent PK)
I need to update some columns in all 3 tables with one 'where' depends on updating columns. So, it will be 3 update statements in one transaction, but the first update changes columns and 'where'  become tampering (for the last two updates).
Is there common way to solve this problem?

For example, there are tables

```
figure(id, name) -- parent table
shape(id, shape) -- shape.id reference to figure.id
color(id, color) -- color.id reference to figure.id
```

I want to update red rectangles to  green squares, that means:

```
UPDATE shape SET shape.shape = 'square' 
   WHERE shape.id = (SELECT id FROM shape
                        INNER JOIN color ON color.id = shape.id
                        WHERE shape.shape ='rectangle'
                              AND color.color = 'red');

UPDATE color SET color.color = 'green' 
   WHERE color.id = (SELECT id FROM shape
                        INNER JOIN color ON color.id = shape.id
                        WHERE shape.shape ='rectangle'
                              AND color.color = 'red');
```

But after first UPDATE there isn't any 'red rectangular', because they became 'square'

So, the question is: do I have to create a temporary table to select ids into  and then perform update or there is another common way?

Comment: Not clear at all, give us table structure, input and desired output

Comment: To add to what @sagi sais: include your queries in your question and properly format them using the code sample button `{}`

Comment: *"do I have to create a temporary table to select ids into and then perform update"* > **Yes**. Do you want me to type out how that's done in an answer or can you work it out yourself?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT shape.id
INTO #tempIds
FROM shape
INNER JOIN color ON color.id = shape.id
WHERE shape.shape ='rectangle'
  AND color.color = 'red'
;

UPDATE shape SET shape.shape = 'square' 
WHERE shape.id IN (SELECT id FROM #tempIds)
;

UPDATE color SET color.color = 'green' 
WHERE color.id = (SELECT id FROM #tempIds)
;
```

Might want to throw transaction and error handling around this too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but is what I want to know  - is this the only/right  way to solve problem like this?

Comment: @ValK No, this is not the only way to do this.  There are many, increasingly complex ways that you might use in different circumstances.  I believe that this is the simplest way, and what I would use unless I had other information or context that would make this approach undesirable.  This is the common way to solve it.

Comment: @@RBarry Young I wasted some hours trying to find any info about this problem but I couldn't! (there are only trivial examples). I know about VIEW and triggers/rules/stored proc, but I wanted to know the  'triggerless' solution for normalized DB. You killed my doubts, thank you!

Comment: @ValK You could also do this by adding a marker of "flag" column to one of the tables, but then you have to alter a table definition and it still takes three statements.